# fire javascript within template when template loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe

I'm using this function (found on SO) to load templates:

```
var loadTemplates = function (list) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var loadedTemplates = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(list, function (name) {
        $.get("templates/" + name + ".html", function (template) {
            $("body").append("<script id=\"" + name + "\" type=\"text/html\">" + template + "<\/script>");
            loadedTemplates.push(name);
            if (list.length === loadedTemplates.length) {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            }
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Here is how I'm calling it:

```
       loadTemplates(['template1','template2']).then(function () {
            $.publish("templates_loaded");
        })
```

I'm successfully subscribing to templates_loaded in my included js files, but now I want to include some js inside a template.  Here is what I have:

```
<div id="test" data-bind="text: alarmIDs().length">Test</div>

<script>
    $.subscribe("templates_loaded", function () {
        alert('test');
    });
</script>
```

And here is the template binding:

```
<span data-bind="template: 'template1'"></span>
```

I do see the "Test" element, but it never fires the alert.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you write [on('change',function(){});](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this?

Answer (score 0):

The JS in your template will run when the template's HTML is turned into DOM elements.  When you load your templates, you're not adding the HTML to the DOM as DOM elements -- you're adding it as text inside the `<script type="text/html">`.  The browser doesn't "see" the code in your template as runnable code because it hasn't parsed it.  That will happen when you actually render the template, using it to generate code (with KO, underscore, or what-have-you).

Update: It appears that this is a limitation of Knockout: script tags inside templates are inserted with being executed.  You could use another templating engine (or simply use jQuery to render your template) to execute scripts at render time.

Comment: I don't follow.  I added a binding and updated the question.  It is binding, which I think is what you mean by "actually use the template to generate code"?

Comment: Your loadTemplates(['template1']) call inserts an element `<script id="template1" type="text/html"></script>` with your template as text inside.  You need to render the template, for example with KO's template binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html): `data-bind="template: { name: 'template1' }"` on some element.

Comment: as evidenced by "I do see the 'test' element", but I have updated my question to explicitly state that I am binding the template.  Sorry.

Comment: Ah! I understand.  I believe this is a limitation of knockout -- updating my answer.